# Need help installing Ubuntu on my new Laptop

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

Hello I have a new laptop with the following specs.

Ci5 5200/ 4GB /1TB/ 2GB Graph/ Win 10 64bit

I need a step by step guide on how to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Win 10 and make it a Dual Boot System. Also I need Grub as my Boot loader and I will not like to use the Win Boot loader.

Also I need the partitioning information too. My current drives are

1) 900 GB single C drive for Data

2) 100 GB Drive with Lenovo Drivers and Backup info

Please do help me.

I did not get any thing about the UEFI and secure boot and what do i need to with it. Why should i disable it ?

Please do tell me about it too
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This guide](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html) pretty much covers everything. Even though it is for Windows 8.1, steps would remain same in Windows 10. Also while installing, I would always suggest you create partitions manually as mentioned in the guide.

Comment: I did not get any thing about the UEFI and secure boot and what do i need to with it. Why should i disable it ?

Please do tell me about it too Thank You.